# HTML Outlook ignores td widths by image

Tags: html, css, html-table, outlook, html-email

I am aware this type of question has been asked before, but the solutions given there are not giving the resolution for me.

I want the `<td>` to have 70% width, but the inserted image is pushing the widths for received emails in outlook (I use MS Outlook Pro 2013). I do not want to use unit `px` because that doesn't work to cover all screen widths. A solution could be to use `<div>` instead of `<td>`, but I was told that `<div>` isn't supported correctly everywhere. Please advise.

**HTML**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="template_header" style="background-color: #fee7f3; color: #ffffff; border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 70%;"><img src="/example.jpg" style="width: auto; height: auto; float: left; box-sizing: border-box;"></td>
            <td style="width: 30%;"><h1>Example txt</h1></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My Attempts**

1. I wrapped the `<img>` with a `<p>` tag
2. I added `display: inline-block` for `<td>`
3. I added attributes `width` and `height` for the `<td>` and `<img>`
4. I added `width: 100%` and `height: auto` for `<img>`

Comment: have you tried putting the width % on the image as well ?

Comment: what you want exactly plz share image

Comment: try  `width:100%; height:auto` on image.

Comment: @MihaiT Sorry, that one I also used. I forgot, I already spend too much time on this:)

Comment: @Ari yes, see point 4

Comment: have you tried to use flex?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that Outlook doesn't support `@media` queries so you can override any set values you need to use in email.

Outlook tends to ignore inline styles for image width. Assuming you want  600px-wide email and your image is 400px, code the width like this:

```
<img src="example.jpg" width="400" style="width: 70%; height: auto;" />
```

Some other things you should be aware of is that box-sizing doesn't work in most email clients. `border-radius` does not work with Outlook.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/box-sizing/
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/border-radius/

Good luck.